# I want my menu to update based on which view I'm on React (alternative to reactdom.render)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-dom

I'm now convinced I am doing this wrong based on the fact that my app doesn't show the menu unless I open dev tools..

On my landing page, I have a menu bar that has the app name/logo as well as menu items and a log in button in my webapp, like this:
[image: landing page menu]

I've added that by having my `main.html` file contain:

```
<div id="render-target">
    <div id="header-container"></div>
    <div id="app-container"></div>
    <div id="footer-container"></div>
</div>
```

and my `main.jsx` file's `render()` function look like this:

```
render(
    <div className='container'>
        <div id="header-container">
            <MenuBar />
        </div>

        <div id="app-container">
            <TableSelect />
        </div>

        <div id="footer-container">
        // some footer code
        </div>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('render-target'));
```

Now, the user can select a "table" and load the data from that, which takes them to a different view.

So, basically from the `TableSelect` view, the user clicks a checkbox and loads a `TableLoad` view, which loads a table for display (in a super not OK way probably, since it calls `ReactDOM.render(<TableDisplay tableId={this.props.id}/>,document.getElementById('app-container'));`)

Then, in the `TableDisplay` view I have

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    ReactDOM.render(<MenuBar currentView="tableDisplay" rows={this.props.rows} cols={this.props.cols} tableId={this.props.tableId} />, document.getElementById('header-container'));
}
```

which calls the `MenuBar` view with the current data properties (or rather, replaces the DOM). What I want to see is below, including the Edit button:

[image: new menu]

This seems to only get triggered unreliably... (though without fail if I have Chrome Dev tools open). I think it's just taking some time for the state to pass and I only show the menu `if (this.state.currentView !== "loadTable" && this.props.cols !== undefined && this.props.rows !== undefined)`.

I guess I know that `ReactDOM.render` is not what I want here, but I want to show the menu even if I don't have column/row data and I need to pass the column/row data once I get it. It feels like a Menu shouldn't need data information, but in order to add data to the table I have to have that data somehow.

---

It's really clear to me that I'm doing a lot of things the non-react way. My app is currently deployed at [ideal-engine.herokuapp.com](https://ideal-engine.herokuapp.com) and the code is at [github repo](https://github.com/adinutzyc21/ideal-engine/tree/master/compareApp), if anyone who knows React and feels altruistic enough to do a code review let me know.

Comment: The only part of a React component that should render anything is the `render` method, which will automatically be called when your props or state change. If you want to render something conditionally, use conditionals in your `render` method. `componentDidUpdate` is not a place to render things.

Comment: this might help https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: You most definitely do not want to call ReactDOM.render anywhere inside of a component. That's the function that renders your app initially, and it shouldn't need to be called more than once.

Comment: as a side note, in your main.html, you don't need  `<div id="render-target">
    <div id="header-container"></div>
    <div id="app-container"></div>
    <div id="footer-container"></div>
</div>` - ALL the inside rendering is taken care of, so it should just be `<div id="render-target"></div>`

Comment: So, as far as I can tell, I can only pass props between children and parents. How can I pass them between siblings?

I have `MenuBar` and `TableSelect` and I need to pass data between them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using a routing solution to help you out, such as [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router), where you can say what component to show at any given route. You can even receive route params (like table ids and such) that will tell you what data to fetch for display.